# Accept list input and list response output using Django Rest Framework

Tags: arrays, json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am getting this part 1 input and part 1 output successfully & documentation is also available for this type of problems Single array
**Part 1 input**

```
{   
    "someid:"1"
    "lecture_id": 1,
    "subject_name": "English",
    "teacher_id": 1,
    "teacher_name": "Cirillo Kierans",
    "room": "Room A",
    "schedule": "1534567899"
}
```

**Part 1
output** posting-->

```
{
    "id:1,
    "someid" :1
    "lecture_id": 1,
    "subject_name": "English",
    "teacher_id": 1,
    "teacher_name": "Cirillo Kierans",
    "room": "Room A",
    "schedule": "1534567899",
    }
```

but my data is not coming like above format and i need to get post response not like above Part 1 , ***i am expecting this multiple record (list) Part 2 input and Part 2 output***

***Part 2 input***

> ```
> {
> "someid:"1"
> "lectures": [{
>     "lecture_id": 1,
>     "subject_name": "English",
>     "teacher_id": 1,
>     "teacher_name": "Cirillo Kierans",
>     "room": "Room A",
>     "schedule": "1534567899"
> }]
> }
> ```
>
> ***Part 2
>   output***
>
> ```
> {
> "lectures": [{
>     "id:1,
>     "lecture_id": 1,
>     "subject_name": "English",
>     "teacher_id": 1,
>     "teacher_name": "Cirillo Kierans",
>     "room": "Room A",
>     "schedule": "1534567899",
>     "someid" :1
> }]
> }
> ```

I have succeeded in getting the listing of data by overriding def list this function
serializers-->

```
class LecturesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    schedule_timestamp=serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model=Lectures
        fields = ('id','lecture_id','schedule_timestamp','subject_name','teacher_id','teacher_name','room')
    def validate(self, attrs):
        travel_date = Lectures.to_date_time(attrs.pop('schedule_timestamp'))
        attrs.update({'schedule_date': travel_date})
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        return attrs

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(LecturesSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        result_data={}
        result_data["lectures"]=data
        return result_data
```

views-->

```
class LecturesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lectures.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return LecturesSerializer       



def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(LecturesViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        data = {}
        data['lectures'] = response.data
        response.data = data
        return response
```

it is giving listing as expected but posting and updating is not working for me, how to define a posting method and getting customized array object response for POST and PUT depicted above
Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Please clarify which one of shown examples is the expected output. And what is `some_id` - is this FK to another model?

Comment: part 2 input and part 2 output ,some_id FK

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely a job for a **nested serializer**:

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialiser):
    lectures = LecturesSerializer(many=true, )
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('some_id', 'lectures', )
```

and remove `to_representation` from `LecturesSerializer`. Editing can be done trough this concept as well.

Comment: i am getting this error --> assert self.child is not None, '`child` is a required argument.'
AssertionError: `child` is a required argument.

Comment: I think this is not the exact solution

Comment: It was kinda pseudo code, I will probably check later if it is missing any options.